# Purpose of NFC readers/writers

Tags: nfc

I want to send data from my RPI to my phone via NFC but I'm confused on the purpose of NFC modules. I thought I would need a writer module to be able to do this but some tutorials online use readers for this which further confused me.

Could someone explain the difference/purpose of NFC readers and writers ?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @joan where should I move this question to ?

Comment: Fun fact: did you know that SD card writers are also SD card readers and are typically called the latter? The same is true for NFC writers.